# Как вывести подпункты многоуровневого меню в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Имеется следующий массив с пунктами и подпунктами многоуровневого меню:

```
<?
$aMenuLinks = Array(
    0 => Array(
        "Дистанции",
        "",
        Array(), 
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1"
        ),
        "",
    ),
    1 => Array(
        "Информация",
        "",
        Array(), 
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1",
            ),
        "",
    ),
    2 => Array(
        "Экипировка",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1"
        ),
        "",
    ),
    3 => Array(
        "Партнеры",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1"
        ),
        "" 
    ),
    4 => Array(
        "Контакты",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1"
        ),
        "" 
    ),

    //подпункты

    5 => Array(
        "Ротонда",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    6 => Array(
        "Тропа Мёбиуса",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    7 => Array(
        "Жар-Птица",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    8 => Array(
        "Бобур",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    9 => Array(
        "Ленивец",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    10 => Array(
        "Штурм неба [Kids]",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "1",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    11 => Array(
        "Положение",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    12 => Array(
        "Программа",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    13 => Array(
        "О Никола-Ленивце",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    14 => Array(
        "Как добраться",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    15 => Array(
        "Проживание",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    16 => Array(
        "Питание",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "2",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    17 => Array(
        "Обязательное снаряжение",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "3",
        ),
        "",
    ),
    18 => Array(
        "Рекомендации по питанию",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "3",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    19 => Array(
        "Рекомендации по снаряжению",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "3",
        ),
        ""
    ),
    20 => Array(
        "Кемпинг",
        "",
        Array(),
        Array(
            "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
            "HAVE_PARENT" => "3",
        ),
        ""
    )
);
?>
```

Необходимо выполнить вывод подпунктов соответствующих пунктов меню в шаблоне сайта. Попытался выполнить `result_modifier.php` следующим образом, однако подпункты не выводятся:

```
$arResult['TOP'] = [];
$arResult['CHILD']['DISTANCES'] = [];
$arResult['CHILD']['INFO'] = [];
$arResult['CHILD']['EQUIP'] = [];

foreach ($arResult as $item) {
    if ($item['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] == 1) {
        $arResult['TOP'][] = $item;
    } elseif ($item['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] == 2 && $item['PARAMS']['HAVE_PARENT'] == 1) {
        $arResult['CHILD']['DISTANCES'][] = $item;
    } elseif ($item['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] == 2 && $item['PARAMS']['HAVE_PARENT'] == 2) {
        $arResult['CHILD']['INFO'][] = $item;
    } elseif ($item['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] == 2 && $item['PARAMS']['HAVE_PARENT'] == 3) {
        $arResult['CHILD']['EQUIP'][] = $item;
    }
}

$arResult['CHILD'] = array_chunk($arResult['CHILD'], 2);
```

Однако ни пункты, ни подпункты меню в шаблоне не выводятся. Как исправить вывод пунктов и подпунктов?
Шаблон для вывода:

```
<ul class="header-menu__wrap">
    <?php foreach ($arResult['TOP'] as $itemTop) { ?>
        <li class="header-menu__item">
            <a href="<?=$itemTop['LINK']?>" class="header-menu__link"><?=$itemTop['TEXT']?></a>

            <div class="header-dd-menu">
                <div class="header-dd-menu__wrap">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php foreach ($arResult['CHILD'] as $itemGroup) { ?>
                                <ul class="header-dd-menu__column col">
                                    <?php foreach ($itemGroup as $itemChild) { ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="header-dd-menu__link" href="">
                                                <?= $itemChild['TEXT'] ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: О боже, это БЭМ что ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так:

*template.php*

```
<ul class="header-menu__wrap">
<?php foreach ($arResult['MENU'] as $itemTop) { ?>
    <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="<?= $itemTop['LINK'] ?>" class="header-menu__link"><?= $itemTop['TEXT'] ?></a>
        <?php if (!empty($itemTop['CHILDREN'])) { ?>
            <div class="header-dd-menu">
                <div class="header-dd-menu__wrap">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php foreach ($itemTop['CHILDREN'] as $group) { ?>
                                <ul class="header-dd-menu__column col">
                                    <?php foreach ($group as $itemChild) { ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="header-dd-menu__link" href="<?= $itemChild['LINK'] ?>">
                                                <?= $itemChild['TEXT'] ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

*result_modifier.php*

```
<?php

$result['MENU'] = [];

foreach ($arResult as $id => $item) {
    if ($item['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] === '1') {
        $result['MENU'][$id + 1] = $item;
    } elseif(!empty($parentId = $item['PARAMS']['HAVE_PARENT'])) {
        $result['MENU'][$parentId]['CHILDREN'][] = $item;
    }
}

$arResult = $result;

foreach ($arResult['MENU'] as &$item) {
    if (!empty($item['CHILDREN'])) {
        $item['CHILDREN'] = array_chunk($item['CHILDREN'], 2);
    }
}
```